# I have 2 image sliders on one page using the same code but only 1 works

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using 2 images sliders on the same page, both are the same but each contain different sets of images. The problem I am running into is that only 1 slider works while the other doesn't move. I don't know why since it is the same HTML, CSS, and JS for both just under different class and variable names.

```
        <video src="./pics/acecs2.mp4" muted loop autoplay controls></video>


      </section>
      <div class="bowl-container">
      <div class="slider-wrap">
        <div class="slider">
          <div class="slider-item">
            <div class="img-div"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="slider-item">
            <div class="img-div"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="slider-item">
            <div class="img-div"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="slider-item">
            <div class="img-div"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="slider-item">
            <div class="img-div"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>





    <section class="showcase2">


      <video src="./pics/ace3.mp4" muted loop autoplay controls></video>


    </section>
    <div class="bowl-container2">
    <div class="slider-wrap2">
      <div class="slider2">
        <div class="slider-item2">
          <div class="img-div2"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="slider-item2">
          <div class="img-div2"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="slider-item2">
          <div class="img-div2"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="slider-item2">
          <div class="img-div2"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="slider-item2">
          <div class="img-div2"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <script src="app2.js"></script>


    let sliderWrap = document.querySelector('.slider-wrap');
    let slider = document.querySelector('.slider');
    let clonesWidth;
    let sliderWidth;
    let clones = [];
    let scrollPos = 1
    let sliderHover = false;
    let req;1
    let items = [...document.querySelectorAll('.slider-item')];
    let images = [...document.querySelectorAll('.img-div')];
    
    
    images.forEach((image, idx) => {
        image.style.backgroundImage = `url(./pics2/${idx+1}.jpg)`
    })
    
    items.forEach(item => {
        let clone = item.cloneNode(true);
        clone.classList.add('clone');
        slider.appendChild(clone);
        clones.push(clone);
    })
    
    sliderWrap.addEventListener('mouseover', () =>{
        sliderHover = true;
    })
    
    sliderWrap.addEventListener('mouseleave', () =>{
        sliderHover = false;
    })
    
    function getClonesWidth(){
        let width = 0;
        clones.forEach(clone => {
            width += clone.offsetWidth;
        })
        return width;
    }
    
    
    function scrollUpdate(){
        if(window.innerWidth > 760){
            sliderWrap.style.overflow = 'hidden';
            if(!sliderHover){
                scrollPos -= .4
            }
    
            if(clonesWidth + scrollPos >= sliderWidth){
                
                scrollPos = 1;
            }else if(scrollPos <= 0){
                
                scrollPos = sliderWidth - clonesWidth - 1
            }
            slider.style.transform = `translateX(${-scrollPos}px)`
    
            req = requestAnimationFrame(scrollUpdate)
        }else{
            sliderWrap.style.overflow = 'scroll';
        }
    
    }
    
    
    function onLoad(){
    
        calaculateDimensions()
        scrollPos = 1;
        scrollUpdate();
    }
    
    function calaculateDimensions(){
    
        sliderWidth = slider.getBoundingClientRect().width;
        clonesWidth = getClonesWidth();
    }
    
    onLoad();

2nd JS page


    let sliderWrap2 = document.querySelector('.slider-wrap2');
    let slider2 = document.querySelector('.slider2');
    let clonesWidth2;
    let sliderWidth2;
    let clones2 = [];
    let scrollPos2 =1
    let sliderHover2 = false;
    let req2; // request animation frame reference
    let items2 = [...document.querySelectorAll('.slider-item2')];
    let images2 = [...document.querySelectorAll('.img-div2')];
    
    
    images2.forEach((image, idx) => {
        image.style.backgroundImage = `url(./pics3/${idx+1}.jpg)`
    })
    
    items2.forEach(item => {
        let clone = item.cloneNode(true);
        clone.classList.add('clone');
        slider2.appendChild(clone);
        clones2.push(clone);
    })
    
    sliderWrap2.addEventListener('mouseover', () =>{
        sliderHover2 = true;
    })
    
    sliderWrap2.addEventListener('mouseleave', () =>{
        sliderHover2 = false;
    })
    
    function getClonesWidth(){
        let width = 0;
        clones2.forEach(clone => {
            width += clone.offsetWidth;
        })
        return width;
    }
    
    
    function scrollUpdate(){
        if(window.innerWidth > 760){
            sliderWrap2.style.overflow = 'hidden';
            if(!sliderHover2){
                scrollPos2 -= .15
            }
    
            if(clonesWidth2 + scrollPos2 >= sliderWidth2){
                
                scrollPos2 = 1;
            }else if(scrollPos2 <= 0){
                
                scrollPos2 = sliderWidth2 - clonesWidth2 - 1
            }
            slider2.style.transform = `translateX(${-scrollPos2}px)`
    
            req2 = requestAnimationFrame(scrollUpdate)
        }else{
            sliderWrap2.style.overflow = 'scroll';
        }
    
    }
    
    
    function onLoad(){
    
        calaculateDimensions()
        scrollPos2 = 1;
        scrollUpdate();
    }
    
    function calaculateDimensions(){
    
        sliderWidth2 = slider2.getBoundingClientRect().width;
        clonesWidth2 = getClonesWidth();
    }
    
    onLoad()
```

Comment: Do these contain duplicate code by any chance? `<script src="app.js"></script><script src="app2.js"></script>`

Comment: @Kinglish yes i just copied the same code but changed the class names in HTML/CSS, and changed the variable names in JS. All code is the same though

Comment: duplicate code isn't good and might be what the issue is, though I can't say.  The same script that runs one slideshow should also run the other, it would just be the initialization that is different.

Comment: @Kinglish yeah it is weird. I ran both of them on 2 separate pages instead of both on the same page and they both worked. I really have no idea what to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use bootstrap with more than one script to run you slide shows or carousels this is how you will have to go about it.

```js
/* 1 carousel */
$('#carousel-1').carousel({
      interval: 4000,
      wrap: true,
      keyboard: true
 });
 
 
 /* 2 carousel */
 $('#carousel-2').carousel({
      interval: 6000,
      wrap: true,
      keyboard: true
 });
```

```css
.carousel img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section class="bg-info text-light text-center py-5 mb-5">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            
            <div class="col">
                <h1>Bootstrap 4 - two and more carousel in one page</h1>
            </div><!-- e col -->

        </div><!-- e row -->
    </div><!-- e container -->
</section><!-- e section -->

<!-- ################### carousel 1 -->

<section class="mb-5">
    <div id="carousel-1" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
       
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carousel-1" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-1" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-1" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-1" data-slide-to="3"></li>
        </ol>
       
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

          <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="https://picsum.photos/1600/400/?image=666" alt="slide">
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
              <h3>1 Lorem ipsum dolor</h3>
              <p>two and more carousel in one page example...</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="https://picsum.photos/1600/400/?image=676" alt="Slide">
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
              <h3>2 Lorem ipsum dolor</h3>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing...</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="https://picsum.photos/1600/400/?image=686" alt="Slide">
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
              <h3>3 Lorem ipsum dolor</h3>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing...</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="https://picsum.photos/1600/400/?image=696" alt="Slide">
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
              <h3>4 Lorem ipsum dolor</h3>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing...</p>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div><!-- e carousel-inner -->
        
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carousel-1" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">prev</span>
        </a>
        
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carousel-1" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">next</span>
        </a>
        
    </div><!-- e carousel -->
</section><!-- e section -->


<section class="bg-info text-light text-center py-5 mb-5">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            
            <div class="col">
                <h2>Carousel 2</h2>
            </div><!-- e col -->

        </div><!-- e row -->
    </div><!-- e container -->
</section><!-- e section -->

<!-- ################### carousel 2 -->

<section class="mb-5">
    <div id="carousel-2" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
       
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#carousel-2" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#carousel-2" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          <li data-target="#carousel-2" data-slide-to="2"></li>
          <li data-target="#carousel-2" data-slide-to="3"></li>
        </ol>
       
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

          <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="https://picsum.photos/1600/400/?image=515" alt="Slide">
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
              <h3>1 Lorem ipsum dolor</h3>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing...</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="https://picsum.photos/1600/400/?image=545" alt="Slide">
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
              <h3>2 Lorem ipsum dolor</h3>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing...</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="https://picsum.photos/1600/400/?image=535" alt="Slide">
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
              <h3>3 Lorem ipsum dolor</h3>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing...</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="https://picsum.photos/1600/400/?image=525" alt="Slide">
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
              <h3>4 Lorem ipsum dolor</h3>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing...</p>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div><!-- e carousel-inner -->
        
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carousel-2" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">prev</span>
        </a>
        
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carousel-2" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">next</span>
        </a>
        
    </div><!-- e carousel -->
</section><!-- e section -->
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```